# Android - What is the name of the circular effect animation that reveals when you fling or drag scroll to the end?

Tags: android, animation, effect

What is the name of the circular effect animation that reveals when you fling or drag scroll to the end on Android?

[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqGm7.png)

To be honest, I'd like to know how this effect is implemented.

Comment: it termed as overlay effect....

Comment: It's called a `preloader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's name is `"OverScroll Edge effect"`. You can try https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride to modify it.